# zurb foundation trouble ordering mobile and stacking causes form input to be unclickable

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using zurb foundation to help me make a website responsive. The idea is that the header should look like this on larger screens (and it does):

```
####### |------ Search ----------| %%%%%%%%%%%
```

And this on smaller screens (which it doesn't):

```
###### %%%%%%%%%%
|---- Search ---|
```

There are two problems. The first is that the mobile one actually looks like this:

```
###### 
|---- Search ---|
       %%%%%%%%%%
```

And the second is that **the Search bar is unclickable**. I tried changing the z-index and making the row show hidden content, to no avail. For the layout I tried push and pull mobile, but that only made things a lot worse. *Code for the layout is below .*

Interestingly, the search button still shows up, and is clickable, even though it should *not* show up, and is in the same form as the search bar.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with zurb foundation? I really, really want to avoid having two different search forms...

---

I changed the scss variables for zurb foundation to the following just for reference

```
$totalColumns: 16;
$mobileTotalColumns: 8;
$columnGutter: 0;
```

I have a header like so:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="three mobile-three columns"></div>
   <div id="search" class="eight mobile-eight columns">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="thirteen mobile-eight columns">
            <!-- text input for search -->
         </div>
         <div class="hide-on-phones hide-on-tablets three columns">
            <!-- Submit button for search -->
         </div>
      </div>            
   </div>
   <nav class="five mobile-five columns">
      <ul class="right">
         <li><%= link_to 'Teams', '#' %></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Records', '#' %></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Settings', '#' %></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a project on git hub that demos the desired behavior.

https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/foundation-ordering-stacking-help

You need to use a combination of **mobile columns** and **source ordering** plus a media query to achieve what you wanted to do.

*Note: The example uses the HTML/CSS version, not the Ruby/SASS version. But that doesn't effect how the code works.*

Comment: I am blown away by the kindness and effort! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I was familiar with what you were trying to accomplish and I thought more people would have similar questions so why not make a solid example to share.