# Zurb Foundation: change the columns number for each breakpoint

Tags: responsive-design, breakpoints, grid-layout, zurb-foundation

I want to create an additional breakpoint with a different behavior for columns for mobile, tablet and dektop.
This is what I'm looking to realize:

**Desktop**:

<----ELEMENT 1----><----ELEMENT 2----><-----SIDEBAR----->

**Tablet**:

<----ELEMENT 1----><-----SIDEBAR----->
<----ELEMENT 2---->

**Mobile**:

<----ELEMENT 1---->
<----ELEMENT 2---->
<-----SIDEBAR----->

I've tried to use the scss function used to add the mobile-n style and switch from 12 columns to 9 columns in the tablet version, but I think I miss something.

```
$tabletTotalColumns: 9;

/* Tablet 4-column Grid */
@for $i from 1 through $tabletTotalColumns {
  .row {
    .tablet-#{convert-number-to-word($i)} { width: gridCalc($i, $tabletTotalColumns) !important; float: $defaultFloat; padding: 0 ($columnGutter/2);
      &:last-child { float: $defaultOpposite; }
      &.end { float: $defaultFloat; }
    }
    &.collapse {
      .tablet-#{convert-number-to-word($i)} { padding: 0; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to one I've answered before: [zurb foundation trouble ordering mobile and stacking causes form input to be unclickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640954/zurb-foundation-trouble-ordering-mobile-and-stacking-causes-form-input-to-be-unc)

Since you are collapsing the columns out of order you will need to use push-pull classes to alter the behavior. The example (lined above) doesn't use sass, but it will give you an idea of what classes need to be used or extended to complete your layout.